# the derivation of the Taylor expansion of the Frobenius norm $\|M-x x^{\top}\|_{F}^{2}$ with linear operator

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion, normed-spaces

Let $d$ be an integer. Let $[d]$ be $\{1,\dots, d\}$. For $\Omega\subset [d]\times [d]$, let $P_\Omega$ be the linear operator that maps a matrix $A$ to $P_\Omega (A)$, where $P_\Omega (A)$ has the same values as $A$ on $\Omega$, and $0$ outside of $\Omega$.

Denote $\|\cdot\|_F$ be the Frobenius norm. Let $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ be a function and $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left\|P_{\Omega}\left(M-x x^{\top}\right)\right\|_{F}^{2}$, where $M\in R^{d\times d}$.

Let $\delta$ be an infinitesimal vector.
Question: How to get the Taylor expansion of $f(x+\delta)$ at $x$?

Supplement: I came across this question at Lemma A.1 of this [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6048-matrix-completion-has-no-spurious-local-minimum)'s supplemental materials. This paper gives an answer as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}f(x+\delta)=& \frac{1}{2}\left\|P_{\Omega}\left(M-(x+\delta)(x+\delta)^{\top}\right)\right\|_{F}^{2}+o\left(\|\delta\|^{2}\right) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\left\|P_{\Omega}\left(M-x x^{\top}-\left(x \delta^{\top}+\delta x^{\top}\right)-\delta \delta^{\top}\right)\right\|_{F}^{2}+o\left(\|\delta\|^{2}\right) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\left\|M-x x^{\top}\right\|_{\Omega}^{2}\\
&-\left\langle P_{\Omega}\left(M-x x^{\top}\right), x \delta^{\top}+\delta x^{\top}\right\rangle+o\left(\|\delta\|^{2}\right) \\
&-\left\langle P_{\Omega}\left(M-x x^{\top}\right), \delta \delta^{\top}\right\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\left\|P_{\Omega}\left(x \delta^{\top}+\delta x^{\top}\right)\right\|_{F}^{2}+o\left(\|\delta\|^{2}\right)\end{aligned}$$
, where $\|A\|_\Omega$ is denoted by $\|P_\Omega A\|_F$.

I tried to understand this derivation using Taylor's theorem for vectors, but in vain. Thus, a detailed derivation is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix $\,P\in\{0,1\}^{d\times d}\,$ such that
$$\eqalign{
P\odot A &= P_\Omega(A)
 \qquad&\big({\rm Hadamard\,product\,projects\,}A{\rm\,into\,}\Omega\big) \\
P\odot P &= P
 \qquad&\big({\rm the\,projection\,is\,idempotent}\big) \\
}$$
Define the matrix variable
$$Y=P\odot(xx^T-M)$$
and use it to write the function in terms of this matrix and calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
f &= \tfrac 12Y:Y \\
df &= Y:dY \\
 &= Y:\Big(P\odot d(xx^T)\Big) \\
 &= \Big(P\odot Y\Big):d(xx^T) \\
 &= Y:d(xx^T) \\
 &= Y:(x\,dx^T+dx\,x^T) \\
 &= (Y+Y^T):(dx\,x^T) \\
 &= (Y+Y^T)x:dx \\
 &= x^T(Y+Y^T)\,dx \\
}$$
Therefore, the first-order Taylor expansion is
$$\eqalign{
f(x+dx) &= f(x) + df \\
 &= f(x) + x^T\Big(P\odot(xx^T-M)+P^T\odot(xx^T-M^T)\Big)dx \\
}$$

---

In several of the steps above, a colon denotes the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$